# Как получить список пользователей чата aiogram?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, aiogram

Условно, есть чат, и в нем пользователи + бот. Как получить список всех USER-ID пользователей через aiogram?

Comment: Официально `Telegram API` не предоставляет такую возможность (смотрите доку telegram API -> https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#available-methods )

Answer (score 0):

Для получения списка всех USER-ID пользователей через aiogram можно использовать метод get_chat_members бота. Этот метод возвращает список объектов ChatMember, которые содержат информацию о каждом участнике чата, в том числе его USER-ID. Для получения только USER-ID можно использовать генератор списков следующим образом:

```
from aiogram import Bot, types

bot = Bot(token="<YOUR_TOKEN>")

async def get_user_ids(chat_id):
    chat_members = await bot.get_chat_members(chat_id)
    user_ids = [member.user.id for member in chat_members]
    return user_ids
```

chat_id - идентификатор чата, для которого нужно получить список пользователей. В функции `get_user_ids` будет возвращен список всех USER-ID пользователей в этом чате.

Comment: нет такого метода

Comment: Простите, используйте вместо ```get_chat_members```: ```get_chat_members_count```

Comment: возвращает число пользователей в чате

Comment: тогда ```get_chat_member```

Answer (score 0):

Чисто через aiogram не выйдет. Придется частично задействовать pyrogram.

Естественно, в начале нужно ввести и запустить в консоли: pip install pyrogram

Потом…

Создаете отдельный файл. И в нем пишете вот это:

```
from pyrogram import Client
api_id = *******
api_hash = "********"
bot_token = "*******"
async def get_chat_members(chat_id):
    app = Client("Имя | Бот", api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash, bot_token=bot_token, in_memory=True)
    chat_members = []
    await app.start()
    async for member in app.get_chat_members(chat_id):
        chat_members = chat_members + [member.user.id]
    await app.stop()
    return chat_members
```

*ПС. Способы получить api_hash и api_id можно найти на сайте pyrogram, в разделе про авторизацию. Или в любых иных источниках, есть даже видео на ютюбе про получение api_hash и api_id.*

И потом в основном коде, где все на aiogram написано, прямо в хендлере, или еще где, импортируете конкретно эту функцию из файла.

```
from {ваш файл} import get_chat_members 
chat_members = await get_chat_members(message.chat.id)
```

И запускаете её, внеся в нее айди чата, в примере - из сообщения полученного  хендлером. И функция вернет как раз то, что вам надо. В представленном варианте возвращаются айди.

Но можно и имена, и статусы в чате. Или прямо в цикле заполнять таблицу SQLite: айдишниками, именами, статусом(админ/создатель/пользователь) и прочим разным.
Главное, лучше не смешивать в одном файле aiogram и pyrogram, а выделить под функцию - отдельный файл, со своими импортами.