# Можно проверять что пользователь подписан на канал через aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Ошибка при вызове get_chat_member что чат не найден("Chat not found"), но если бот присутствует в нужном чате ошибки нету . Можно сделать так чтоб бот мог вызывать get_chat_member без нахождения в группе.

Comment: а что за ошибка?

Comment: и каким образом вы ведете проверку, можете приложить минимально исполняемый пример?

Comment: Ошибка "Chat not found" , код просто запуск метода с нужными параметрами

Comment: какими "нужными" параметрами...

Comment: При таком подходе к задаче вопроса, я не думаю что сообщество способно вам помочь, ознакомьтесь пожалуйста с тем, как нужно задавать вопросы https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: id чата и юзера . get_chat_member(chat_id="Тут id", user_id= "Тут id юзера") , если бот присутствует в нужном чате ошибки нету

Comment: а, ну разумеется, в контексте бота - бот не знает о группе, чтобы понять что пользователь находится в группе, необходимо добавить его в эту группу, это прям написано в документации aiogram -> https://docs.aiogram.dev/uk_UA/latest/api/methods/get_chat_member.html это так же дублируется в документации к API Telegram -> https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchatmember

Comment: с другой стороны могу вам предложить попробовать pyrogram по этому ответу -> https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1529343/470029

Comment: Спасибо, попробую